# Post and get data from form using localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have a simple form and div

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input name="username">
  <textarea name="msg" rows="10"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="ok" value="Send" >
</form>
<div id="comments"></div>
```

How to create get and post data from form to div using localstorage?

And data also must stay there after the user refresh the page by checking localstorage.

It's something like local posted comment on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to get data from your form. I advise you to modify your inputs to have unique ids or classes for easier access:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input id="username" name="username">
  <textarea id="msg" name="msg" rows="10"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="ok" value="Send" >
</form>
<div id="comments"></div>
```

I'm assuming you are using jQuery, since it's in your tags, so you can get the data with jQuery like this:

```
var username = $('#username').val();
var message = $('#msg').val();
```

Then you need to save it into the local storage. Since you said that it will be something like comments, I'm assuming there will be many of them, so you need to use an array:

```
localStorage.comments = localStorage.comments || [];
localStorage.comments.push({
  username: username,
  message: message
});
```

And that's it! You can then access it from anywhere by using `localStorage.comments`. Local storage exists on global `window` object, so you don't need to do anything special to access it, you can simply read it and write to it from anywhere.

You can see more examples on how to use localStorage [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Answer (score 0):

Then what you need is a session storage,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

This blog can help you

http://www.thomashardy.me.uk/using-html5-localstorage-on-a-form

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');
```